# Which ISO is intended for document management systems?

Tags: standards, iso, document-management

I'm currently tasked to create a document management system that complies with ISO (International Organization of Standardization). Problem is, I don't know what ISO fits and / or is intended for a document management system.

Can anyone help me out? The system is going to be made using web tecchnologies, such as PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know "The document managements system" is the part of ISO 9001 Quality Management System. Try to dig this ISO.

For PHP/MySQL you need the web-server like "Apache" and connect both PHP and MySQL to this server. I've used "DENVER project" that install all three (Apache, PHP, MySQL) in one packet.

Comment: I've got no problems setting up PHP and MySQL, what I'm having trouble with is deciding the correct ISO. But following your tip, I tried searching through and have decided that I'm gonna use 9001:2008.